# capture bitmap from view android

Tags: android

I have posted same question but it's in near to my problem that's why i have posted it second time

Hi i want to capture image from RelativeLayout, for that i have used below code

```
   captureRelativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   bitmap = captureRelativeLayout.getDrawingCache(true).copy(
                Config.ARGB_8888, false);
```

the problem is that when i start activity and get image from that view at that time it will work fine, but if i use it second time, the image is not being refreshed, means that previous bitmap is every time i getting.

Now if i close my activity and agian start it then i will get updated image but again not in second time
:( for more information look at the
[can't share image properly android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091089/cant-share-image-properly-android)

Comment: What I can advice is: ... save the bitmap with a different name from time to time. Base the file name on the current time (might be enough if it's accurate to the seconds, I think. If not, use milliseconds too).

Comment: @ArtooDetoo or time+date :)

Comment: Yes, what I meant: **yyyyMMdd_HHmmss**, to be exact - with your app name prepended ;)

Comment: i have tried with random number with 100000 but in every new image it's storing it's previous image, the main issue is, getting the view is not refreshing

Comment: i tried and work with captureRelativeLayout.getDrawingCache(false).copy(
     Config.ARGB_8888, false);if it your required answer or not let me know.

Answer (score 8):

Here are two ways to convert a view to a bitmap:

## Use Drawing Cache:

```
RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

I've had some issue with the drawing cache method when the view is very large (for example, a `TextView` in a `ScrollView` that goes far off the visable screen). In that case, using the next method would be better.

## Use Canvas:

```
RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
if (bgDrawable != null) {
    bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
} else {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
}
view.draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score 7):

You should destroy the drawing cache after copying it, so the cache will be built again next time you call `getDrawingCache()`.

The code would look like this:

```
captureRelativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = captureRelativeLayout.getDrawingCache(true).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, false);
captureRelativeLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Or like this if you don't want to enable the flag:

```
captureRelativeLayout.buildDrawingCache(true);
bitmap = captureRelativeLayout.getDrawingCache(true).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, false);
captureRelativeLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Reference: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/IkRXuMtOA5w/zlP6SKlfX-0J

Answer (score 2):

There is a Kotlin extension function in Android KTX:

```
val config: Bitmap.Config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
val bitmap = canvasView.drawToBitmap(config)
```

Comment: where canvasView bro?

Answer (score 1):

finally i got solution from this [view.getDrawingCache() only works once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988847/view-getdrawingcache-only-works-once)

i just forget to put

```
     captureRelativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

i have done it by below code,

```
    try {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = null;
        }
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        captureRelativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File f = new File(sdcard, "temp.jpg");
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        captureRelativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        bitmap = captureRelativeLayout.getDrawingCache(true).copy(
                Config.ARGB_8888, false);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        captureRelativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f)); // imageUri
        sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg");

        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f)); // imageUri
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Image"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As DrawingCache is depracated then in kotlin:

```
fun View.createBitmap(): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    Canvas(bitmap).apply {
        background?.draw(this) ?: this.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
        draw(this)
    }
    return bitmap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
>
> view.buildDrawingCache();
>
> Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();

"bitmap"     is the final bitmap..